# ASP.NET Core 6 Partial View "InvalidOperationException"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, partial-views

I want to show my create view into my main view which is index. So I take a partial view which is `_Create.cshtml`. But after calling the partial view, I get an `InvalidOperationException`.

This is my `index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<CommercialERP.Models.SelectList.BuyerSelectList>

<section class="content" style="display: block;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <div class="card card-primary card-outline card-outline-tabs">
                <div class="card-header p-0 border-bottom-0">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Create</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Details</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                            <partial name="~/Areas/Admin/Views/BuyerSelectList/_Create.cshtml"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm align-middle m-0" id="header">
                                <tr class="m-0" style="text-align:center;background-color: #17A2B8">
                                    <th width="20%">
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Buyer)
                                    </th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                @foreach (var BuyerSelectList in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr class="m-0">
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => BuyerSelectList.Buyer)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group mx-auto" role="group" style="width:100%">
                                                <a asp-controller="BuyerSelectList" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@BuyerSelectList.Id" class="btn mx-2" style="background-color: #17A2B8">
                                                    <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" style="width:100%">
                                                <a asp-controller="BuyerSelectList" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@BuyerSelectList.Id" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                                                    <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is `_create.cshtml`:

```
@model CommercialERP.Models.SelectList.BuyerSelectList

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Buyer" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Buyer" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Buyer" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-end m-0" style="border: 1px solid #99CCFF; height: 40px; width:100%; padding: 2px; background-color: #17A2B8">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="background-color: #5E5A80; width: 160px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my `BuyerSelectListController`:

```
namespace CommercialERPWeb.Areas.Admin.Controllers.SelectList
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class BuyerSelectListController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public BuyerSelectListController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<BuyerSelectList> objBuyerSelectListList = _unitOfWork.Buyer.GetAll();
            return View(objBuyerSelectListList);
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(BuyerSelectList obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Buyer.Add(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Row Created Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(obj);
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var objBuyerSelectListList = _unitOfWork.Buyer.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (objBuyerSelectListList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(objBuyerSelectListList);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(BuyerSelectList obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Buyer.Update(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Row Edited Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(obj);
        }

        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var objBuyerSelectListList = _unitOfWork.Buyer.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (objBuyerSelectListList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(objBuyerSelectListList);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeletePOST(int? id)
        {
            var obj = _unitOfWork.Buyer.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _unitOfWork.Buyer.Remove(obj);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            TempData["success"] = "Row deleted successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CommercialERP.Models.SelectList.BuyerSelectList]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'CommercialERP.Models.SelectList.BuyerSelectList'.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Your `_create.cshtml` is waiting to receive the `CommercialERP.Models.SelectList.BuyerSelectList` and the data model is passed to the `index.cshtml` is `IEnumerable<CommercialERP.Models.SelectList.BuyerSelectList>`.  Therefore, seems like you should render the `_Create.cshtml` inside the `@foreach (var BuyerSelectList in Model)` loop and pass the iterating item `BuyerSelectList` as data model to the `_create.cshtml` partial view. Will be look like **`<partial name="~/Areas/Admin/Views/BuyerSelectList/_Create.cshtml" model="BuyerSelectList"/>`**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the correct model.  Replace the partial tag with the following:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Areas/Admin/Views/BuyerSelectList/_Create.cshtml", 
          new BuyerSelectList())
```